# Puppet Nodes.pp Include Modules Execution Order

Tags: provisioning, puppet

I am trying to set a sequential order on some of my modules for certain nodes.

```ruby
node basenode{
 include ps
 include netfx
 include hg
 include reportviewer2012
 include wdeploy30
 include sqlexpress2008
 include windowsrolesfeatures
 include tcbase
}

node 'myserver' inherits basenode  {
 include tcuiagent

 Class['tcuiagent'] -> Class['tcbase'] -> Class['windowsrolesfeatures'] -> Class['ps']
}
```

Certainly I DON'T want to set dependencies within the module resources because that will make them interdependent which I don't want to do. In this case, I want to accomplish this order.

1. ps (first one)
2. windowsrolesfeatures
3. anyotherpackage {hg,netfx...}(dont care the order of provisioning)
   n. tcbase
4. tcuigant(last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to express relationships between modules, you can use stages to enforce an order.

You must first declare the stages in your top manifest :

```ruby
## Very important : we define stages.
## Can only be done here.
stage { 'first': }      # the first of first
stage { 'apt': }        # to install apt sources and run apt-get update if necessary
# stage main            # default stage, always available
stage { 'last': }       # a stage after all the others
# Now we define the order :
Stage[first] -> Stage[apt] -> Stage[main] -> Stage[last]
```

Then use them :

```ruby
# basics needing a run state
# We use the "class" syntax here because we need to specify a run stage.
class
{
   'puppeted': # debug
      stage   => first, # note the explicit stage !
      ;
   'apt_powered': # Very important for managing apt sources
      stage   => apt, # note the explicit stage !
      #offline => 'true', # uncomment this if you are offline or don't want updates
      ;
   'apt_powered::upgraded': # will systematically upgrade paquets. dev machine -> we want to stay up to date
      stage   => apt, # note the explicit stage !
      ;
}
```

But this is ugly and this is not what stages are made for.

Comment: I guess i dont have other choice. 

1. Create Relationship between resources even they belong to different modules. Example(netfx40,netfx45,sql2012). In this case i have three modules but the dependency chain is as it was declared sql2012->netfx45->netfx40. Guessing you can not redistribute the sql2012 module without the other modules.

2. By using stages i am creating the relationships at the top level but the resources are not independent anymore since they have a variable "stage" that needs to be set at the site.pp

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest rewriting the modules so that the order they are installed is not important anymore or create the necessary relationships to the resources.

If you are installing/configuring related resources from different modules, you could consider merging those modules.

Ger.

Comment: If I create relationships between the resources then you are making resources from different modules dependent and i do want to create that relationship at the top level but using stages look really ugly.

Comment: Great name! I envision a treed bear hurling apples down willy-nilly on an unsuspecting picnicker.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I solve it using a different approach with node inheritance.

```ruby
node windowsmachine{
 include ps #powershell 
 include windowsrolesfeatures #windows roles and features
 include netfx #netframework 4.0 and 4.5
}

node teamcitybase inherits windowsmachine {
 include hg #mercurial
 include nuget #nuget configuration
 include reportviewer2012 
 include wdeploy30 #web deployment 3.0
 include tcbase #asp.net configuration
 include sqlexpress2008 #sqlexpress
}

node 'myserver1','myserver2' inherits teamcitybase{
 #pending installation of puppet clients
}

node 'myserver3' inherits teamcitybase  {
 include tcuiagent 
}
```

Windows Machine configuration modules do not depend on each other but `myserver1` with the sqlexpress2008 depends on that baseline.

No stages or Module dependency!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

After releasing the same problem i came across the following post which work the best from all that i have found.

```
 1 #####################
 2 # 1) Define the stages
 3 #####################
 4 
 5 stage { 'prereqs':
 6  before => Stage['main'],
 7 }
 8 
 9 stage { 'final':
10  require => Stage['main'],
11 }
12 
13 #####################
14 # 2) Define the classes
15 #####################
16 
17 # We don't care when this class is executed, it will
18 # be included at random in the main stage
19 class doThisWhenever1 {
20 
21 }
22 
23 # We don't care when this class is executed either, it will
24 # be included at random in the main stage
25 class doThisWhenever2 {
26 
27 }
28 
29 # We want this class to be executed before the
30 # main stage
31 class doThisFirst {
32 
33    exec {'firstThingsFirst':
34      command => '/bin/echo firstThingsFirst',
35    }
36 }
37 
38 # We want this class to be executed after the
39 # main stage
40 class doThisLast {
41 
42   exec {'lastly':
43      command => '/bin/echo lastly',
44    }
45 
46 }
47 
48 #####################
49 # 3) Assign the classes 
50 # to a stage
51 #####################
52 
53 class { 'doThisFirst': 
54   stage => prereqs,
55 }
56 
57 class { 'doThisLast':
58  stage => final,
59 }
60 
61 
62 include doThisFirst
63 include doThisLast
```

http://pipe-devnull.com/2013/09/20/puppet-ensure-class-execution-ordering.html

Regards